# Create new file in GitLab via Ansible

Tags: ansible, gitlab

The script for my ansible job is located in a gitlab repository.
E.g.: */Ansible/job.yaml*

I want to create a new file from my Ansible job that contain the response of another Ansible job that I run in the same location as my job script.
E.g.: */Ansible/ouput.txt*

Is it possible? Usually I put the file to the server host but this time I need it to be in GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

Given that GitLab do let you write in that folder indeed, you can:

- [delegate the task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks) to write to localhost
- use the [special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic-variables) `playbook_dir` to write it in the same folder as the playbook

So, something like:

```yaml
- copy:
    content: "{{ some_other_registered_task_output }}"
    dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/output.txt"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

---

Mind that if you are targeting multiple hosts in that playbook, you will have to aggregate all nodes registered output, otherwise you will end up with the output of one node only.

Which you can achieve with something like:

```yaml
- copy:
    content: "{{
        hostvars
        | dict2items
        | selectattr('key', 'in', ansible_play_hosts)
        | map(attribute='value.some_other_registered_task_output')
        | join('\n\n')
      }}"
    dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/output.txt"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

---

For example, the two tasks:

```yaml
- command: echo '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
  register: some_other_registered_task_output

- copy:
    content: "{{
        hostvars
        | dict2items
        | selectattr('key', 'in', ansible_play_hosts)
        | map(attribute='value.some_other_registered_task_output.stdout')
        | join('\n\n')
      }}"
    dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/output.txt"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Run on nodes called `node1`, `node2` and `node3`, would create a file *output.txt*, in the same folder as the playbook, on the controller, containing:

```
node3

node1

node2
```

Comment: i tried using playbook_dir and it successfully read my gitlab directory but the new file is not generated in my gitlab